# Temporary Table Losing All Rows, Unless Selected Individually?

Tags: postgresql

new to PostgreSQL and having some issues. I've got a long set of code utilizing a lot of temporary tables with one "main" temporary table that is being updated with the contents of every other temporary table. However, one of these tables is not working like the others. Here's the code for it:

```
--cargo and dwt creation
drop table if exists t_cargo;
create temp table t_cargo as
select
    a.*,
    b.dwt,
    (b.dwt * .98) as cargo
from
    t_vessel_list a
join
     tanker b on a.imo = b.imo;
--end

--select * from t_cargo

--update cargo and dwt
UPDATE t_vessel_list
SET metric_tons = b.dwt,
vessel_cargo = b.cargo
FROM t_cargo b
WHERE t_vessel_list.vessel = b.vessel;
--end
```

This table is not being called anywhere else in the query, and yet this table has no data when it is run as part of the entire query. It'll only have data and update it correctly if it's run individually (as in, highlighted and then ran). Otherwise, it's empty and the update results in empty columns.

As requested, here's a second temp table that is inside the query that does work:

```
--create a table for draught data, separate because joins will filter
drop table if exists t_ais_draught;

create temp table t_ais_draught as
select distinct
    a.*,
    b.date,
    b.destination,
    b.poi,
    b.draught
from
    t_vessel_list a
join lateral
    (
    select * from asvt_position b where a.vessel = b.vessel order by 2 desc 
    limit 1
    ) b on true;
--end


--update draughts
UPDATE t_vessel_list
set v_draught = b.draught
FROM t_ais_draught b
where t_vessel_list.vessel = b.vessel;
--end
```

This set of code works, and has minimal difference from the first. All the codes in the query look either like the first or second temp table codes, and all except the one i linked at the top work fine.

**After some more trial and error, i found the solution was to move the temp table and update call to a later portion of the query. It doesn't look to be messing with any other part of the query after doing so, but I still don't understand why this didn't work in the first place. As mentioned, the t_cargo table isn't called anywhere in the query outside of the code posted.

Can anyone explain what happened?

Comment: There must be a mistake somewhere. Temporary tables don't just lose their data.

Comment: Your code seem ok, but your question isnt clear. Can you write two separated code and  show which one work and which one doesnt. Also provide some sample data so we can try reproduce the problem.[**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i've added a second code that works.

Comment: My guess is the select doesnt have any data at the moment of the `CREATE TABLE` because you are working with temporal tables. Check the order of creation. Also you can test it using a real table you know have data.If you get update then you know where is the problem.